# Getting channel ID from a name

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I want to send a message to a channel that the bot has created! There is no possible other way to get id than to search by name! I did the following:

```js
let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `${v}id`);
```

And did not work! I searched up on stack overflow and added `.id` at the end:

```js
let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `${v}id`).id;
```

Still did not work! And I can't figure out why... Here is the sending part and the error that occured:

Sent message:

```js
channel.send("Created new channel!);
```

Error:

```js
C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\events\premium.js:45
            channel.send("Created new channel!");
                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\events\premium.js:45:21)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:556:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:499:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a channel that's name is `<whatever "v" is>id`.

You need to do

```js
let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === nameOfChannel).id;
```

If this errors, you might need to use `[...].first().id`.

**EDIT:** For some reason, using `${v}` didn't work here. The asker changed it to `1id` and it worked.

Comment: usage of 'id' as method or member is inconsistent with this answer. Is that on purpose?

Comment: id is 1 btw so "1id"! its searching for a channel named after "1id"

Comment: @TimHallyburton Made a mistake, meant `.id`

Comment: @ChilledBlueFire So you do want to get a channel named literally `1id`?

Comment: Yes! (Because its for a pannel I am making, its weird)

Comment: @ChilledBlueFire when you log the result of the find operation, is it a `<Something>Channel {` or a `Collection [Map] {`?

Comment: @LoganDevine When I do log with .id it crashes and when I do nothing it gives undefined

Comment: Log the whole object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229262/discussion-between-logan-devine-and-chilled-bluefire).